# Python: help in organizing the output in columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the program written down. It just randomly lists "genetic code" in form of binary digits for the parasite and host. All i want is help in organizing the output. I want the output to be in columns - for example :

```
Host     Parasite
  1      [1,0,0,1]          
  2      [1,0,0,1]
  3      ......
  4      .......
```

and list of parasite random numbers in the other column next to the host

```
import random
host_genome_length = 10
assert host_genome_length >0
parasite_genome_length = 5
assert parasite_genome_length>0
host_initial_population=10
assert    host_initial_population >=1
parasite_initial_population=2
assert   parasite_initial_population >=0
parasite_initial_chance_1= 0.1
assert   0<= parasite_initial_chance_1 <=1
host_initial_chance_1=0.5
assert   0<= host_initial_chance_1 <=1

hosts=[]
for i  in range(host_initial_population):
    genome= []
    for j in range (host_genome_length):
        if random.random()< host_initial_chance_1:
            genome.append(1)
        else:
            genome.append(0)
    hosts.append(genome)
print "hosts:"
print  hosts

parasites=[]
for i  in range(parasite_initial_population):
    genome= []
    for j in range (parasite_genome_length):
        if random.random()< parasite_initial_chance_1:
            genome.append(1)
        else:
            genome.append(0)
    parasites.append(genome)

for i in range(host_initial_population-parasite_initial_population):
    parasites.append(None)
print "parasites:"
print parasites
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's string formatting tools for this. The `:40` part of each bracket specifies that the field should be 40 characters wide:

```
print "{:40} {:40}".format("Host", "Parasite")
for host, parasite in zip(hosts, parasites):
    print "{:40} {:40}".format(host, parasite)
```

Output:

```
Host                                     Parasite                                
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                         
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                         
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]           None                                    
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]           None                                    
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]           None                                    
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]           None                                    
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]           None                                    
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]           None                                    
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]           None                                    
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]           None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatexamples) function.

Here is some sketch of what you might come up with.

```
print '{:50} {:50}'.format('Host', 'Parasites')

for i in range(max(len(parasites), len(hosts))):
    print '{:50} {:50}'.format(str(i+1) + str(hosts[i]), parasites[i])
```

Here is the output produced by that snippet on your code:

```
Host                                               Parasites                                         
1[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                   
2[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                   
3[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]                    None                                              
4[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]                    None                                              
5[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]                    None                                              
6[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]                    None                                              
7[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]                    None                                              
8[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]                    None                                              
9[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]                    None                                              
10[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]                   None
```

You might wanna beautify it a little more.