# Python: calculating the numbers in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My output looks like

```
100010
101010
101001
None
None
None
```

For the next part of the program I need to count the number of digit sequence. For example of this it should be 3.  How do I do that. The first part of the program basically generates a random binary sequence (representing parasite genome) And none means that there are no parasites for the host. These are generated randomly.  (This might be different when I run program each time). I just need to calculate how many parasites are there. This should be done in python.

Comment: What's the code that generate that output? Edit the post with it please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617079/python-help-in-organizing-the-output-in-colums: here is the link to the code

Answer (score 1):

Using [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> lst = [1000010, 101010, 101001, None, None, None]
>>> sum(x != None for x in lst)
3
```

Alternative: subtract the number of `None` from total number:

```
>>> len(lst) - lst.count(None)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = '100010 101010 101001 None None None'
import string
wordsList = string.split(input)
i=0;
for word in wordsList:
    if word != 'None' :
        i= i+1
print i
```

The 'i' gives you the result 3

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: L = [100010, 101010, 101001, None, None, None]

In [3]: sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n is not None, L))
Out[3]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you collect all your output into a list like so:

```
    collection = ['100010', '101010', '101001', None, None, None]
```

you can create a new list using list comprehension:

```
    parasites = [item for item in collection if item is not None]
```

which will give you the list `['100010', '101010', '101001']`. Then you can find the length of this list to give you the number of parasites:

```
    len(parasites)
```

which gives you `3` in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617079/python-help-in-organizing-the-output-in-colums i have a part of my programming here i am trying to  fit it in this code.