# Python: counting the numbers in the list:

Tags: python, python-2.7

here is the link to  a part of my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617079/python-help-in-organizing-the-output-in-colums

now what i need to do is  suppose that my output looks like

Host
100010

101010

101001

1001001

Parasite
10001001
10001000
10010001
None
None 
None

for the next part of the program i need to count the number of digit sequence in parasite list . For example for  the  parasite section this  should be 3. ( I basically take everything- (the number of none)  How do i do that.

Comment: You should update your original question.

Comment: @chrisaycock No, this is a different question from the other one. He should format his question properly and include relevant code in this question though.

Answer (score 2):

> "I basically take everything- (the number of none)"

In Python:

```
>>> parasite = [[1,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],None,None,None]
>>> len(parasite) - parasite.count(None)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat underspecified.  But.  It looks like your elements of your list are either sublists (containing something, doesn't matter) or `None`.  So:

```
parasite = [[1,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],None,None,None]

sum(map(bool,parasite))
Out[27]: 3
```